# getting plainText password of Dotnet Nuke based on Salt

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I have a client who is using DNN. Now I have to use same user base for a Python based system that needs to use same userbase. For this purpose Password is needed in plaintext to store in other system so that same plaintext password could be use for DNN validation. I have Salt and encrypted password. DNN based user/password will be stored in FlatFile based system hence retrieval of passwords in plain text needed. How do I fetch plaintext password

Comment: Are you trying to get the DotNetNuke password from the database in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke just uses SqlMembershipProvider to store usernames/password.  So, the code to decrypt a password would look something like:

```
byte[] encodedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPwd);
byte[] bytes = this.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword);
if (bytes == null)
{
  return null;
}
return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0x10, bytes.Length - 0x10);
```

Comment: No need to mention salts? and from which table I can get encrypted passwords along with userName?

Comment: 1. The salt is just appended to the password, so the "-0x10" takes care of that. 
2. The membership info is in the DNN database, stored in the aspnet_* tables.  Also, if you are trying to decrypt from outside the dnn framework (not in a module), you need to set the machinekey to be the same in you exernal app's config file.  If you do this inside a module, it's VERY simple: 
string userPassword = UserController.GetPassword(ref uInfo, String.Empty);

Comment: Just google "Decrypt DNN password" or "Decrypt SqlMembership Provider" and you'll get a ton of help.  It's been a while since I did this and I don't have my old project around.